# Parsing XML with Document Builder

Tags: android, xml, inputstream, document

In my application I'm trying to download a file from a FTP-server and convert the retrieved inputstream to a Document object, so I will be able to parse the XML.
I did this before and it worked just fine, but for some odd reason the conversion to a Document object keeps running and will not finish. This is really weird considering I didn't modify any of my code. Here is my code:

```
     public Document download(Document document){
            Log.d("Download", "Attempt to download file");
            String remoteFile;
            InputStream inputStream;
            try{
                String rootDirectory = ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory();
                FTPFile[] locatedFiles = ftpClient.listFiles(rootDirectory);
                int x = locatedFiles.length;
                if(x != 0){
                    remoteFile = locatedFiles[0].getName();
                    Log.d("Download", "File detected");
                    try{
                        ftpClient.setBufferSize(1024*1024);
                        inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(remoteFile);
                        Log.d("Download", "File retrieved");
                        try{
                            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                            Log.d("Download", "Builder object made for converting file");
                            try{
                                document = builder.parse(inputStream); // This is the piece of code which keeps running and never finishes
                                Log.d("Download", "File converted");
                                try{
                                    inputStream.close();
                                    User.getInstance().setDownloadedDay(User.getInstance().getCurrentDay());
                                    User.getInstance().setDownloadedMonth(User.getInstance().getCurrentMonth());
                                    User.getInstance().setDownloadedYear(User.getInstance().getCurrentYear());
                                    Log.d("Download", "Closed input stream");
                                }catch(IOException e){
                                    Log.e("Download", e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }catch(SAXException e){
                                Log.e("Download", e.getMessage());
                            }catch(IOException e){
                                Log.e("Download", e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }catch(ParserConfigurationException e){
                            Log.e("Download", e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }catch(IOException e){
                        Log.e("Download", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.w("Download", "No file detected");
                }
            }catch(IOException e){
                Log.e("Download", e.getMessage());
            }
            return document;
        }
```

The Log where it says "File converted" never pops up, which indicates the conversion is still in progress. I've tried multiple XML files to solve my problem (like smaller ones), but my application keeps failing this process.
Can someone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I checked my FTP-server and it didn't run well.
So I rebootet my laptop and tried to run it again.
My application runs fine at the moment, it wasn't the code, it was a problem with the server.